# f is a function from R to R and J is bounded in interval in R

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Let $f(x)=1+x$ on $ J_{1}=[0,1]$ and $ J_{2}=[0,3]$ 
So, (A) ,(B) and (D) hold. 
c be sigmun function with f(x)= 0 for x=0 , -1 for x<0 and 1 for x>0.
so on [0,1] $W(f,[0,1])=1   $

Please help !!

Comment: It's not really clear what is the question? Do you want help showing these, or are you trying to determine if (C) is true?

Comment: please help in determing c and  am i correct so all options will hold .

Comment: Also perhaps show what you've tried, or thought.

Comment: and no option will be correct

Comment: (B) is not correct,  your other two statements seem true

Comment: how please explain

Comment: Your comments are too short to know what you want exactly. First, please edit your question so it is clearer. Second, would you like for me to explain all that I said or just why (B) is false? If you add your own reasoning, it would help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: please explain all and  i want to know the correct approach how to solve these sorts of question.

Comment: So do you no longer need the explanation? Because Xiao showed you how to approach this, but not to actually do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87524/discussion-between-sejy-and-keen-ameteur).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very common misconception.

If you want to show a statement is true, you have to show for all possible functions and all possible intervals that satisfy the assumptions in the statement, the conclusion in the statement holds. For example in $(A)$, you have to show for ANY function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and ANY two bounded intervals $J_1 \subset J_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ (these are the only assumptions), we have (the conclusion)
$$W(f, J_1) \leq W(f, J_2).$$
You can not pick your function $f(x)$ and your intervals $J_1, J_2$.

On the other hand, if you are trying to show a statement is false, it suffices to construct a function $f$ and a bounded interval (or intervals) that satisfy the assumption and yet the conclusion fails.

Comment: Awesome solution. I am having doubt in last option. By definition of continuity |f(x) -f(a)| < epsilon when x is in (a-delta,a+delta). Maybe we can say |sup(f(x)) - f(a) |  < epsilon . But how to conclude for sup(f(x)) -  inf(f(x))

Answer (score 2):

What you tried to give to prove (C) is actually an example and not a proof. Notice first that $W(f,J)\geq 0$ always.  Perhaps it would be more useful to see for a function $f$ on interval $J$, if $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2\in J$, what can you say about $W(f,J)$ (A lower estimate)?

As Xiao said to show that (B) is false, it suffices to find an function $f$ and a sequence of intervals $J\supseteq I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq ...$ with lengths tending to $0$ such that $W(f,J_n)\not \rightarrow0$. Try looking for a bounded function with a dicontinuity at $a\in I_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

For (A), notice that if $J\subseteq I$, then $\sup\{ f(x) :x\in J \} \leq \sup\{ f(x) :x\in I \}$ and $\inf\{ f(x) :x\in J \} \geq \inf\{ f(x) :x\in I \}$. Use these facts to show (A).

For (D) write what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $a$ in terms of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. This should give an obvious sub-interval to work with.

If you still struggle after these hints, write in a comment to this answer and I'll explain further.